# talking incoming caller ID in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I wish to make an app in android which should speak the caller Name or number when an incoming call comes. I don't have any idea about where should i start. Can anyone help me?
Can i able to include android's default speech app into my application

Comment: i googled it many times, but i cannot find any solution

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this but you can try this thing

register MyPhoneStateListener first.

```
private class MyPhoneStateListener1 extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                           // the incoming number is is the one you wanted
        }
    }
}
```

Now use some [TextToSpeech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html) api to convert the incoming number to speech. i have not used the TextToSpeech so can not give more advice on it.

ANd if you want to get the name then use the following to get the contact name

```
Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
 resolver.query(uri, new String[]{PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME} .....)
```

Comment: i also thought about your suggestion, but will it override the ringtone? instead of ringtone it should speech the contact name...

Comment: I am not sure about this as I haven't tried but this the only way you can try. If not works then no way to do this without custom rom ..